# Using Razor to replace variables in my html email template

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor

I've been using Razor to replace some variables in my html email template, with values from my application.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252" />
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>
<p>Dear @Model.Document.DocumentAddresses[0].Address.Salutation @Model.Document.DocumentAddresses[0].Address.FirstName @Model.Document.DocumentAddresses[0].Address.LastName,
<p>Our test code:
    @foreach (var item in Model.ProductList)
    {
        <span>Your product of choice: <a href="@item">products name</a></span>
    }
 end of test code
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

That all worked as expected, and now I wanted to add some more data into the emails.
I wanted to add a link to the customers favorite products in our webshop.
So I added that data:
{ ProductName = Product name, ProductLink = https://example.com?productid=4321 }
But I cannot get any further than the above emample.
The @item is showing just the data if I view the source code of the email, but if I want to use something like @item.ProductLink to create the url and @item.ProductName to display the products name, it crashes the razor replacement of all variables.
The error message I get is that the "object does not contain a definition for ProductLink"
Now I'm stuck and looking for some help with this.

```
class EmailProductLink
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductLink { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Which .NET version are you using, and can you share the transformation code too? The template itself doesn't provide much information.

Comment: Can you share the structure of `Model.ProductList`?

Comment: @Yiyi You I've added the class